# How to detect if an object is in the "line of sight" of another object using math.atan2 function?

Tags: python, pygame, trigonometry

I'm having serious problems trying to understand how to "detect" if something is in the imaginary "line of sight" of the player. I've created a simple wall. The idea is to print something if the player is aiming at the wall and hit the mouse click button at the same time.

Here's my code:

```
import sys
import pygame
import math
pygame.init()

screen_width = 640
screen_height = 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
running = True

class Actor:

    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h

class Wall:

    def __init__(self):
        Actor.__init__(self, 300, 100, 128, 32)
        self.surface = pygame.Surface((self.w, self.h))
        self.surface.fill((0, 0, 0))

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.surface, (self.x, self.y))

class Player(Actor):

    def __init__(self):
        Actor.__init__(self, 0, 0, 64, 64)
        self.surface = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("GFX/player.png"), (self.w, self.h))
        self.rotated_surface = self.surface.copy()
        self.rect = self.surface.get_rect()
        self.directions = [False, False, False, False]
        self.speed = 0.1
        self.running = False

    def rotate(self):
        mouse_x = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]
        mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]
        angle = math.atan2(mouse_y - (self.y + (self.w / 2)), mouse_x - (self.x + (self.w / 2)))
        angle = angle * (180 / math.pi)
        rot_image = pygame.transform.rotozoom(self.surface, -angle + 270, 1)
        rot_rect = self.rect.copy()
        rot_rect.center = rot_image.get_rect().center
        self.rotated_surface = rot_image

    def move(self):
        if self.directions[0]:
            self.y -= self.speed
        if self.directions[1]:
            self.y += self.speed
        if self.directions[2]:
            self.x -= self.speed
        if self.directions[3]:
            self.x += self.speed
        if self.running:
            self.speed = 0.2
        else:
            self.speed = 0.1

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.rotated_surface, (self.x, self.y))
        pygame.draw.aaline(screen, (0, 255, 0), (player.x + (player.w / 2), player.y), pygame.mouse.get_pos())

    def fire(self, actor):
        bullet_x_pos = self.x + (self.w / 2)
        bullet_y_pos = self.y
        # ...

player = Player()
wall = Wall()

def redraw():
    screen.fill((75, 0, 0))
    player.draw()
    player.move()
    wall.draw()
    pygame.display.flip()

while (running):
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if e.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                sys.exit()
            if e.key == pygame.K_w:
                player.directions[0] = True
            if e.key == pygame.K_s:
                player.directions[1] = True
            if e.key == pygame.K_a:
                player.directions[2] = True
            if e.key == pygame.K_d:
                player.directions[3] = True
            if e.key == pygame.K_LSHIFT:
                player.running = True
        elif e.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if e.key == pygame.K_w:
                player.directions[0] = False
            if e.key == pygame.K_s:
                player.directions[1] = False
            if e.key == pygame.K_a:
                player.directions[2] = False
            if e.key == pygame.K_d:
                player.directions[3] = False
            if e.key == pygame.K_LSHIFT:
                player.running = False
        elif e.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            player.rotate()
        elif e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            print("Yep")

    redraw()
```

Here's the image:

[image]

There's not enough material on the web about it, especially for Python / Pygame (I guess shooters are not very common on the library). I have no idea how to return a boolean based on the angle returned from atan2, telling me that the player is aiming at the object.

Comment: There's a lot of information on the web about it, the problem is called "ray casting"

Comment: That, or basic high school math, which can also be found on the web. You need to be more precise about what you don't understand.

Comment: You are looking to evaluate a ray / rectangle intersection.  The `atan2` function will not be necessary.

Comment: so you have the angle with the horizontal? Then the tangent of that angle (which should be in radians and between 0 and pi in your scenario where the wall is above the player) should be the slope m of the ray (line). Use y-y1=m(x-x1) where (x1, y1) is your point where the player's ray gun is. Then I think  would go after this is to set y to be the value it is for the wall, find the corresponding x, and see if it is in the range between (inclusive, probably) the endpoints of the wall. There may be something more elegant, but this approach explains itself in terms I hope are familiar.

Comment: @JeremyKahan that sounds more like an answer then a comment.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Maybe, but there is no code in my comment at all and nothing Python-specific. I am suggesting how the person could proceed without doing it. I have gotten burned (downvoted) before putting what I thought was an answer in and being told it was not, so I am a bit gun-shy here.

Comment: `x,y = <coordinates of wall> ; x1, y1 = <coordinates of guy> ; m = (y-y1)/(x-x1)` Boom you have (abstracted) code! anyway we are kind of getting side tracked from the actual question so I'm just going to say I think it is worthy of being an answer and leave it there.

Comment: "There's not enough material on the web about **it**"  Some question you always have to ask yourself when searching the internet: What exactly is **it**?  Is there other way of phrasing **it**?  What could be other closely related topics?  This problem is not at all specific to shooter games made in pygama, at very least you should have tried [calculate line of sight python](https://www.google.ca/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=calculate+line+of+sight+grid&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=N9kSWI2RCKeC8Qel3ZfoAg#q=calculate+line+of+sight+python)

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, although I know how to program in Python, I'm quite the beginner in trigonometry (That's why I've included it as a tag). I'm not going to blame the poor education in my country, since I could have studied it by myself, but I'm trying. Any answer provided here will help me to understand it better through Python / Pygame (Pygame provides a pretty good "visual" way of understanding things). Searching for raycasting and atan2 on the internet looks like rocket science to me, and I just get lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's atan2 is kind of magical in which one does not have to play around with signedness of "x" and "y" directions in order to get a full 360 angle.
Ant Python's math model even have a function ready to convert the radian result back to degrees (then, only add 360 to negative numbers to get 0:360 range instead of -180:180).

That given, with a little care on getting the positions correctly - you can check the minimum and maximum angles of a rectangle's "line of sight" relatively to a given position by checking all of the rectangles corners directions, and picking the most extreme values. 
That said, due to the cyclic vales found, there are lots of corner cases -  I think I've covered them all.

```
class Actor(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h

    def __len__(self):
        return 4

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return {0: self.x, 1: self.y, 2: self.w, 3: self.h}[item]


def get_direction_range(rect, position):
    min_d = 181
    max_d = -181
    # Due to the cases where the target rect crosses the 180, -180 line, always keep the bottom corners last:
    for corner in (('top', 'left'), ('top', 'right'), ('bottom', 'left'), ('bottom', 'right')):
        tx, ty = getattr(rect, corner[1]), getattr(rect, corner[0])
        print(tx, ty)
        # Calculate vector from given position to target corner
        vx = tx - position[0]
        vy = -(ty - position[1])

        direction = math.degrees(math.atan2(vy, vx))
        if direction < min_d and (not (direction < 0 and min_d > 0 and min_d > 90) or min_d == 181) :
            min_d = direction
        if direction > max_d or (direction < 0 and max_d > 0 and max_d > 90):
            print(direction, "max")
            max_d = direction
    min_d += 0 if min_d > 0 else 360
    max_d += 0 if max_d > 0 else 360
    return min_d, max_d


def check_target(direction, position, rect):
    if not isinstance(rect, pygame.Rect):
        rect = pygame.Rect(rect)
    if position in rect:
        return True

    min_d, max_d = get_direction_range(rect, position)
    if max_d < min_d:
        max_d, min_d = min_d, max_d
    if abs(max_d - min_d) > 180:
        return max_d <= direction <= 360 or 0 <= direction <= min_d
    return min_d <= direction <= max_d


def dl(scr, pos, direction):
    xx = math.cos(math.radians(direction)) * 200
    yy = -math.sin(math.radians(direction)) * 200
    pygame.draw.line(scr, (0,255,0), pos, (pos[0] + xx, pos[1] + yy))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

You could  make that "Actor" class derive from pygame.Rect (if you can't use Rect itself) - I added methods on it so it at least can be cast to Rect, which allows us to easily pick the corner coordinates.
Anyway, note that if you are using Python 2.x (I believe so, due to the difficulty there is to install pygame under Python3), all your classes *should* inherit from `object`.

The `dl` function I've used to debug in aliving session - it ay be usefull to you as well.